# Using selenium webdriver to test on multiple browsers

Tags: user-interface, testing, selenium, browser, selenium-chromedriver

information: using visual studio 2012, creating a .Net webproject
             Running (latest versions) selenium with chrome and firefox.
             UI testing - before my implementation of the foreach loop and list works perfectly

i want to be able to run the test once and it occur across both of the browsers, simultaneous or one after the other is not too important but i am having trouble trying to code this...

below is a snippet of the simplicity and roughly the way i wanted to try and code this and being a novice when it comes to this i was wondering if anyone can help me out and also not make it too complex.

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver _driver;


            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArgument("--start-maximized");


            var verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();

            List<object> browserList = new List<object>();

            browserList.Add(_driver = new ChromeDriver(options));
            browserList.Add(_driver = new FirefoxDriver());

            var _browser = browserList;

            foreach (object element in browserList)
            {
                _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://myURL.com/");
                _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Username")).Clear();
                _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Username")).SendKeys("Username");
                _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).Clear();
                _driver.FindElement(By.Id("Password")).SendKeys("Password");
```

and so on... im not sure if this sort of code is even passable and would work? any help would be much obliged!

Comment: NUnit and other test frameworks cover this sort of things out of the box. Why don't you use them?

Comment: im using Nunit but personally i cant seem to figure it out or find the answer else where - and being such a novice i dont feel confident to convert to selenium rc or grid yet where agreeably that would be far easier from what ive read.

Comment: Selenium RC or Grid don't come into it - you can get this working using NUnit and parameterised tests (which is literally just the concept of passing parameters to your tests, in this case, you pass the browser you want to use into your test methods). Being new to a subject does not stop you from researching and improving your knowledge of the subject :)

Comment: as i said i have researched and tried to find a feasable if not easy to follow answer as to how to do it. and i have been researching and trying to find how to do it but as i have said to no avail currently, and selenium rc and grid both come into it - there are many ways to do it im looking for one similar way to my layout as to do it - maybe you should check out some more on selenium grid especially... it is made for handling the exact kind of process im looking to achieve, maybe youre not understanding my question correctly. thanks anyway.

Comment: No, Selenium Grid is meant for handling this stuff in a scalable way, farming the tests off to several different VM'S. You haven't mentioned that. The basic, first pass, of what you want can be done in NUnit. You seriously can't of searched *anywhere*: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12372529/run-webdriver-nunit-tests-on-multiple-drivers